# ¿Por qué al colocar determinados números en la consola me da error InputMismatchException?

Tags: java, java-11

Resulta que el código, como pueden ver, es demasiado sencillo, y cumple la función prometida de cuestionar al cliente y luego mostrarle los datos en pantalla sobre lo que ingreso. Sin embargo, al momento de colocar el número de teléfono, me percate que al colocar un número (por ejemplo 1254354024) no pasaba nada, pero si ponía un número como 3544256425 me manda este error. Eso pasa con cualquiera de los enteros y, w & z.

```
*Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException: For input string: "3544256425"
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2264)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2212)
    at g.f.main(f.java:17)*
```

```
package g;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class f {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        /*CAPTURA DE DATOS
          DESCRIPCION:
          Se capturan datos de una persona y luego se le retorna en una sola linea de codigo de consola.*/
        int y,w,z;
        String a,b;
        float v;saf
        
        Scanner x = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.println("Hola, por favor ingrese su nombre");
        a = x.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Ahora su apellido");
        b = x.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Su documento de identidad");
        y = x.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Su numero de telefono");
        z = x.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Su edad");
        w = x.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Por ultimo, su estatura");
        v = x.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Hola " + a + b + ", su documento de identidad es " + y + ", su numero de telefono " + z + ", su edad " + w 
                + " y su estatura es de " + v + " M");      
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EL problema es que el número 3544256425 es mayor que la capacidad de almacenamiento de un `int`, por lo cual hay que usar un `long`:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class f {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        /*CAPTURA DE DATOS
          DESCRIPCION:
          Se capturan datos de una persona y luego se le retorna en una sola linea de codigo de consola.*/
        long y,w,z;
        String a,b;
        float v;
        
        Scanner x = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.println("Hola, por favor ingrese su nombre");
        a = x.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Ahora su apellido");
        b = x.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Su documento de identidad");
        y = x.nextLong();
        System.out.println("Su numero de telefono");
        z = x.nextLong();
        System.out.println("Su edad");
        w = x.nextLong();
        System.out.println("Por ultimo, su estatura");
        v = x.nextLong();
        System.out.println("Hola " + a + b + ", su documento de identidad es " + y + ", su numero de telefono " + z + ", su edad " + w 
                + " y su estatura es de " + v + " M");      
    }
}
```

Saludos.

Comment: También tener en cuenta el espacio en memoria que ocupa cada variable, en este caso el tipo **int** ocupa 32 bits por lo que los valores que permite estarían entre -2^31 y (2^31)-1. Mientras que el de tipo **long** ocupa 64 bits y los valores que permite están entre -2^63 y (2^63)-1